# Astro JS site builder: Include worker (or other companion library) in build

Tags: vite, service-worker, astrojs

I'm building [a web app](https://github.com/chadoh/entire-life-offline-first/) that relies heavily on a [background Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API)

Background workers are essentially little companion libraries that you write that are loaded separately from the rest of the application JS. Here's how I successfully load a worker in `astro dev`:

```
const worker = new Worker(new URL('./' + type + '/worker.ts', import.meta.url), {
  type: 'module',
})
```

(Code copied from https://github.com/chadoh/entire-life-offline-first/blob/2509a2014a017a3a44ec3d2f8b45bc45d05fd772/src/data/backends/findOrCreateWorker.ts#L26-L28)

[The worker itself](https://github.com/chadoh/entire-life-offline-first/blob/main/src/data/backends/google/worker.ts) can import ES modules from some files that are also used by the main app JS (all authored in TS):

```
import { numToLetter, grab, StaleAuthToken } from './worker-utils'
import { localStorageStuff } from '../../local'
```

In short, I need to:

1. actually build the `worker.ts` file, even though nothing `import`s it
2. know the file path of the built `worker.js` in the main app JS
3. know the file path of the built `worker-utils.js` and `local.js` modules in the worker JS

Let's just focus on step 1, for now.

**1. Actually build the `worker.ts` file, even though nothing `import`s it**

Vite allows building in [Library Mode](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode). The [simplest config](https://github.com/chadoh/entire-life-offline-first/pull/3) I've come up with:

```
export default defineConfig({
  site: 'https://new.entire.life',
  integrations: [react()],
  vite: {
    sourcemap: true,
    build: {
      lib: {
        entry: new URL('src/data/backends/google/worker.ts', import.meta.url),
        formats: ['es'],
        fileName: 'googleWorker',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

However, this still doesn't change Astro's build behavior at all. Why not? How do I actually include my worker/companion-library file in the build?